# adding or routing additional domain email addresses

Tags: exchange-2007

We have exchange 2007 and we bought a new domain name and we're still keeping the old one so that we can wean everyone off of the old emails.

Now, I'm wondering how to go about this.  I need to add the new domain as accepted and authoritative by the exchange server. Emails on the new domain need to get routed to the inbox and ditto the old emails, however, I want to be able to change the reply-to in the header to the new email address automatically.  I also want to set the new email addresses as the defaults.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to add a message at the bottom of every externally outgoing email saying that the new email is xxx.yyy@newdomain.org. But this is a nice to have, certainly not a must have.

I've added the new domain as authoritative, and managed to change the primary smtp email addresses to the new one, but sent emails are not being routed to them and neither are the old email addresses!

Now how the heck would I go about fixing all of that? I'm completely stumped!

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps you need to do this should be as follows:

- Add the domain as an accepted domain in Exchange Management Console (or shell)
- Setup each user with their new email address, on there email addresses tab, or setup a Email address policy to handle this for all users.
- Set this new address to being the default address for the user.

If you have done each of these steps, then it should work. If you are getting an error message when sending email to your new domain, then you need to take a look at the reason supplied in the error message (and post it here) and see why this is happening. It could be a DNS issue, is mail actually getting to Exchange in the first place, could be an issue with exchange accepting mail to that domain, or could be an issue with the specific user.

Answer (score 0):

have you added the address with the new domain to the recipients e-mail addresses in Exchange Management Console?

You'll need to end up with something like:
xxx.yyy@olddomain.com
xxx.yyy@newdomail.com

For a single user, right click on the mailbox, and select properties, and then click on the "email addresses" tab.   I'm sure there is a way to do this with powershell, but I have not had to do a bulk of these yet.

Comment: Yeah, that's been done to all of them and for a time I set the new emails as the primary smtp email addresses for all the users but any emails sent to the new addresses returns with a failure.

Comment: Can you attach a copy of the return message?  In our environment, inbound mail travels through a Sendmail server before Exchange sees it, so we have to remember to set the aliases in both places.  Plus we use Postini for inbound SPAM filters, so we have to set it there.  In our case seeing which server rejected the message tells us where we missed it.